# Sulu cms find page by category and tags

Tags: symfony, sulu

How can i find list of pages by assigned category and tags?

I am adding page from backend and assigning category and tags in to it.

In frontend in my custom controller action i want to list pages by category. So how can i do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the content-type smart-content (http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/reference/content-types/smart_content.html) which is able to filter pages by categories and tags. This criteria's can be configured by the content-manager in the Sulu-Admin.

If this is not what you need you could also use the search-index in the controller to query for pages. See an example here https://github.com/sulu/sulu/blob/develop/src/Sulu/Bundle/SearchBundle/Controller/WebsiteSearchController.php#L97

Comment: In addition to filtering by tags, I also need to filter pages by date. Can you help me to find best way to do this?